# Is there a C++ compiler warning or linting tool that warns when calling a method not defined in a concept constrained type?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, clang++, clang-tidy

For some concept...

```
template<class T> concept can_meow = requires (T t){
   t.meow();
};
```

... is it possible to get a warning when the following is called?

```
void func(can_meow auto& anim){
    anim.woof(); // warn here - e.g. 'can_meow does not define woof'
}
```

Comment: That was supposed to be a compile-time error when concepts were initially introduced. However when concepts got into standard requirements for these checks were not there for some reason, making concepts rather useless.

Comment: I was pondering the idea of writing a macro library that would generate both a concept and a minimal type conforming to it, which could then be used to test templates. Doubt I could convince anyone to use it though.

Comment: Just to clarify, what you would like to have is a warning when the body of `func` does not use anything the `concept` checks, correct? I don't think this is possible anyway...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm

Comment: @Erel: Rust do it. I should be doable with clang tooling.

Comment: @Barry Hmm, on the first glance this looks more like an imitation of C++20 concepts, that doesn't check function bodies.

Comment: @Jarod42 OP asks for a warning, not for a diagnostic by a static analyser, hence my question. But yes, by "possible" I meant "possible using compiler flags", rather than "absolutely impossible by all means". My bad for the poor wording.